# ufw deny rule seems to be ignored

Tags: ufw

I have UFW setup as my firewall and a script that reads my log file to detect spammers (it's a mailserver). The script insert rules like these on the first line:

Anywhere DENY x.x.x.x

The script is running fine, rules are added. You would say everything is working fine, but there are still logs coming from IPs that should be blocked.

I have tried reloading UFW, but this does not solve this issue. These are basically my rules:

- Anywhere DENY x.x.x.x
- 25/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
- 443/tcp ALLOW Anywhere

I assume the firewall stops when the rule is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once a rule is matched the others will not be evaluated.

You can check the order of your rules and that ufw is active with:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```